# Projection problems when importing KML from Google Earth to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, kml

I want to open several points that I exported from Google Earth as a KML in QGIS for further use. I can import the data and the points are displayed but something must be wrong with the projection as the points are plotted somewhere completely different.

When I open the KML separately the projection of the file is in WGS84 EPSG:4326 (which was also the setting of the original project). I enabled projection on the fly and also tried exporting the KML as a shapefile in different projections but it didn't work.

Is it maybe due to the fact the data are formatted in degrees / minutes and how can I adjust that?

I use QGIS 2.0.1 on a Mac.

Comment: The kml I have are all written in decimal degrees. Can you  add the extent of the kml layer, as listed under Properties, Metadata? Does the kml align in a project with EPSG:3857 and Openlayers plugin Google background?

Comment: Thanks, AndreJ. The extent says: 
`xMin,yMin -94.799,38.8556 : xMax,yMax 7.92842,53.7906` The reference system says: `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`. The .kml-data allign fine with an OpenStreetMap-Background, which is in EPSG: 3857. However, when I then try to add one of my layers, they remain invisible. The same thinh happens when I change my project to EPSG: 3857.

Comment: So it is rather a problem of your other layers, not the kml one. Make sure they have an extent that fits to their layer CRS.

Comment: KML coordinate reference system is not [EPSG:4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326).  The [standard](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-007r2/12-007r2.html) tells us `The KML encoding of every kml:Location and coordinate tuple uses geodetic longitude, geodetic latitude, and altitude (in that order) `  EPSG:4326 uses longitude/latitude order